# htaccess rule blocking robots.txt file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I have following rule inside my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

and I added that to make sure all pages on my website are 301 to pages with slash `/` at the end. Now it has the problem because google reported it's getting coverage issues with my `robots.txt` file because it is getting `/` at the end as well. How do I exclude the `robots.txt` file from that rule?

Comment: Is `robots.txt` present in the document root? If that's the case (and you are not internally rewriting the request to a `robots.txt` file elsewhere, or routing the request to generate `robots.txt` dynamically) then the _condition_ you already have should prevent the slash from being appended. If not then all your static resources would also end up having a slash appended (and break)?

Comment: you are right, we had robots.txt added trough AIOSEO plugin, but when I made it as physical file on server its working just fine now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including a condition that excludes requests that look as if they have a file extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

If nothing else, this should serve as an optimisation. However, as noted in comments, the `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REQUEST_FILENAME` should already exclude requests for `/robots.txt` - assuming this exists as a physical file in the document root and is not internally rewritten to another file or routed through your application to generate `robots.txt` dynamically?

Comment: Correct, I made a physical file of robots.txt and it's working fine now. I had it through AIOSEO plugin before that since its a WordPress website. Thanks for help!